# How to implement continuous animation in Pubnub Realtime System NO USER INTERACTION

Tags: javascript, jquery, pubnub

I am developing an app that will continually animate like showing the loading animation bar in real time.

Animation steps:

1. The div box will show a loading animation bar with an image
2. When it is finished loading it will change the image.
3. Next step is to show the loading animation bar again. Wait until it finished.
4. When loading finished it will change the image and show the loading animation bar
   again.

Steps above will continuously processs with NO USER INTERACTION.Only the loading animation will handle all the changes.

I read the documentation in PubNub but it seems we need a user interaction to be able to change the display on the website. But In my case there's no user interaction.

How can I implement this kind of app?

Is this possible in pubnub?

Comment: You have posted this question in so many places. Twice to Stack Overflow, which is forbidden. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846374/pubnub-background-processes-for-an-auction-app-development
I think that is why you other post got down voted (wasn't me though). We also got your private support ticket. Once you question is resolved/answered in one place, please do us all a favor and update with it everywhere you posted.

Answer (score 0):

No user interaction is required for PubNub to send and receive messages.  What you are going to need is some sort of function that is called when the loading animation bar finishes loading.  When the loading bar finishes loading, call a function such as this:

```
var UniqueID = PubNub.generateUUID(); //Generate a unique id for user
pubnub.publish(
    {
        message: {
            uuid: UniqueID,
            finishedLoading: true
        },
        channel: 'testChannel',
        sendByPost: false, // true to send via posts
    });
```

Remember you have to import the PubNub SDK, and also have the subscribe function.  When you create your code to receieve the message, it will look something like this:

```
window.listener = {
    status: function(statusEvent) {

    },
    message: function(messageEvent) {
        if(messageEvent.message.finishedLoading === true) {
           // Run your picture creation and new loading bar creation code here
        }
    } 
pubnub.addListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you for you wonderful response. However I think you miss one thing. What I meant is that the loading bar needs to be in real time. I was thinking that we need to develop a server side auction process on our server. This process will start the auction and the loading bar. When we want to start this process all its data will be broadcast to end user, using pubnub api.

Comment: That would be possible with PubNub since PubNub would update everyone in real time with the progress. You would do so in the same way, however I don't have code to hand over to you regarding that.  Just send a publish message every auction process.

Comment: But I think I need to put it on my own server not on pubhub. Someone already answer the question in here. Let me know what you think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846374/pubnub-background-processes-for-an-auction-app-development.