# Pubnub: Background Processes for an Auction App Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pubnub

Hello I am developing an auction app like tophatter.com. I want to implement an application that has background process in it. I want this process to run forever until I stop it

http://eoction.com thatss our current site. The problem on our site when we refresh the page the auction also restart. We need something like a continuous process like tophatter.com if you refresh the page it will load the updated auction process.

I found this great service called pubnub. I am thinking we need a background process for this? This will process the auction on the pubnub blocks and then when we visit the site we will just need to query on its updated process?

Does pubnub support something like this?

Comment: Thank your for the down vote with no explanation.

Comment: No idea why it was down voted originally, what your asking about isn't easy to just google and doesn't require code to be answered. I've set it back to it's original state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PubNub Web Page Best Practices

When user refreshes your web app page or navigates to another page there are things you need to consider as a web app developer no matter what technologies you may be using. I will address, at a high level, the things you need to do when PubNub is integrated into your web page.

### Restore Parameter

Whether the user interrupts your connection to PubNub or it is a network failure, you will want PubNub to reconnect and continue where it left off as much as possible. The [PubNub JavaScript SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) has a initialization parameter called *restore* that when set to true, will reconnect to PubNub and get missed messages after the connection is dropped and reestablished.

```js
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey: "mySubscribeKey",
    publishKey: "myPublishKey",
    ssl: true,
    uuid: getUUID();
    restore: true
});
```

### Reuse UUID

It is important to reuse the same UUID for each end user as this will allow PubNub to identify that user uniquely when it comes to Presence so that it doesn't produce new `join` events for the same end user. The PubNub [JavaScript SDK actually generates a UUID and stores it in localStrorage and reuses it by default](https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043671-how-do-i-set-the-uuid-) but very likely you have your own UUID that you would like to use for each of your end users.

### Last Message Received Timetoken

If the network disruption is brief as is the case with a page refresh or page navigation, then missed messages are retrieved when `restore:true` is implemented in the `init` as stated above. But when the user is offline for more than say 5 minutes, you may want to retrieve missed messages on one or more channels. The best way to do this is to keep track of the *timetoken* of the *last received message* by storing it in localStorage every time a message is received via `subscribe` callback. When the user comes back online and it is has been more than 5 minutes since they were last online, [call `history` using this *last received message timetoken* on each channel](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference#history) that you need to get missed message from.

### Subscribe to Channels

Finally, you'll want to make sure that the user is subscribed to the channel they expect to be based on what their state prior to the connection disruption. If it is a page refresh, you likely just want to resubscribe them to the same list of channels. To do this, you just need to keep a list of channels they are currently subscribed to, once again, in localStorage. If the user navigates to a new page and this causes a full page reload (modern web apps should not require this, but...) then you may want to unsubscribe from some channel(s) and subscribe to new channel(s), it just depends on what that page navigation means to your app. Modern web app frameworks do not require full page reload for page navigation since the web app acts more like a desktop app than older web apps. And again, if the the user was offline for quite some time (more than 5 minutes) then it may not make sense to subscribe them to the same channels that they were subscribed to before. Really depends on your use case.

And by the way, Tophatter uses PubNub ;) but all of the above are generic best practice guidelines and recommendations and is not referencing any one app in particular.

> EDIT: To address you question specifically, as pointed out in comments below...

You can't implement long-running process in PubNub BLOCKS (not currently, anyways), so you will need a server process for this. When the user refreshes the page, you just need to hit your server for current state. If using PubNub to keep this progress bar updated in realtime, you just subscribe to that channel that is sending the state of that progress bar and update your client. Using the same best practices I provided above are still necessary.

Comment: Thank you for you wonderful response. However I think you miss one thing. What I meant is that the loading bar needs to be in real time. I was thinking that we need to develop a server side auction process on our server. This process will start the auction and the loading bar. When we want to start this process all its data will be broadcast to end user, using pubnub api.

Comment: But if this can be achieve in pubnub BLOCKS Event Handler then pubnub is truly server-less..

Comment: OK this is the answer I am looking for thank you for your time and patience with my grammar :D